# how to get latest commited files in Git

Tags: git, command-line

I want get latest changed files of my repository.

to do it:

I have run this command to get latest Commit ID:

```
git log --format="%H" -n 1
```

and then I paste output to this command:

```
git diff-tree -r --no-commit-id --name-only --diff-filter=ACMRT "PREV_COMMAND_OUTPUT" | xargs tar -rf changedFiles.tar
```

Now, how I can merge These commands and pass output if first output as argument of second command?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on linux (OSX might also work) and have access to a *real* shell (sorry, windows won't work) you can use command substitution:

```
git diff-tree -r --no-commit-id --name-only --diff-filter=ACMRT $(git log --format="%H" -n 1) | xargs tar -rf changedFiles.tar
```

or

```
git diff-tree -r --no-commit-id --name-only --diff-filter=ACMRT `git log --format="%H" -n 1` | xargs tar -rf changedFiles.tar
```

But since you're always using the last commit ID, you might as well just replace the whole command with `HEAD`

```
git diff-tree -r --no-commit-id --name-only --diff-filter=ACMRT HEAD | xargs tar -rf changedFiles.tar
```